# Installing efibootmgr at end of Ubuntu install on Mac

Tags: system-installation, uefi, mac

I've installed Ubuntu on my Mac Mini from a USB drive. The instructions on the [web site](https://theredblacktree.wordpress.com/2014/07/29/installation-guide-for-linux-mint-17-ubuntu-14-04-on-apple-mac-mini-late-2012/) that I followed to do the install says I should not reboot at the end of the process. Instead I should "get a terminal" and run

```
sudo apt-get install efibootmgr
```

When I key ctrl opt t, it briefly flashes a progress bar then returns to the installation app. At the point in the install where it asks you to reboot, I chose back. That gave me a menu where I chose "Execute a shell". When I ran the command, it tells me that I will be running ash with a bourne shell and the new file system is on "/target. At this point I entered the comnand. It said sudo was not found. When I run it without sudo, it says apt-get is not found. Typing help displays all the available commands. It's very limited. I found apt-get in /target/usr/bin. When I try to run it, I get permission denied. I even get permission denied on trying to run sudo in the same directory. I then copied apt-install from its target directory to the local ram image. It ran, but gave an error about a missing library. Next, I did a chown root /target and tried to run it from its original location. I got the same error about a missing file.

Comment: looks like a typo - should be `apt-get` (or just `apt`), not `api-get`. If that's not the issue, please copy & paste the exact error you are getting into your question (pretty sure it's meant to be an Ubuntu command, nothing to do with OSX) (oh and you may need to run `sudo apt update` first)

Comment: @Zanna, I updated the question.

Comment: Hmm anyway it's an Ubuntu command and an Ubuntu package. It sounds like (from the instructions) it should be run in the Ubuntu live environment (assuming that's what you were using). Run the installer, open terminal using Ctrl+Alt+t, then enter the command. But that also seems a bit odd. Could you link to the instructions you followed?

Comment: @Zanna, more updates.

Comment: Still not exactly clear what you're at, but I suggest you boot the USB again and select Try Ubuntu without installing. You should find the terminal application - search for it in the dash? Then see if you can run the command. You definitely don't want anything in OSX for that command...

Comment: @Zanna, fixed it by creating a new bootable USB with desktop live on it. I booted from it, "got a terminal", and ran efibootmgr. Turn your comments into an answer and I'll accept it. I hate accepting my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instructions on that site become suddenly vague at the crucial point.

```
sudo apt-get install efibootmgr
```

is most definitely an Ubuntu command and nothing to do with OSX

The guide seems to assume you're running the graphical installer program (ubiquity) from a live environment. Although it just says "boot the USB and install as normal" I would elaborate slightly

1. After creating a live USB of the desktop edition of Ubuntu, turn your computer off and on again and select the USB in the boot menu or firmware settings (accessed with whatever method your hardware requires)
2. At the initial menu select **Try Ubuntu without installing**
3. When the desktop loads, click on the **Install Ubuntu** icon
4. Select your options... If not dual booting, **Erase the disk and install Ubuntu**, allowing the installer to partition for you, and not choosing LVM, is the simplest formula.
5. According to the instructions, when told to reboot, rebelliously refuse and instead open a terminal, by clicking the terminal launcher icon, searching for "terminal" in the dash, or pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> (wait, what's that on a Mac?)
6. Enter the command in the terminal... and that should be it.